# how to insert paragraph after codeblock with <pre> in summernote

Tags: django, summernote

i want to insert

tag after i use codeblock with ext-highlight

below is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- default css -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/reset.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/layout.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- use Prism -->
    <link href="{% static 'css/prism.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- bootstrap cdn -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- fontawsome -->
    <link href="{% static 'fontawesome/css/all.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- summernote -->
    <link href="{% static 'summernote-0.8.18-dist/summernote-bs4.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="{% static 'summernote-0.8.18-dist/summernote-bs4.min.js' %}"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="id_content></textarea>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#id_content').summernote({
        toolbar: [
          ['style', ['style', 'add-text-tags']],
          ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'clear']],
          ['color', ['color']],
          ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
          ['table', ['table']],
          ['insert', ['highlight', 'link', 'picture', 'video']],
        ],
        width: '100%',
        height: '380px',
        lang: 'ko-KR',
        prettifyHtml: false,
        placeholder: '질문을 입력하세요.',
        dialogsInBody: true,
        tabDisable: true,
      });
    });
    </script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/summernote-ext-highlight.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
```

now insert codeblock

`<p></p> + <pre></pre>`

but i want

`<p></p> + <pre></pre> + <p></p>`

now my page like this
[image]

but i want like this
[image]

How can I make the features I want?

I don't know if I asked the question correctly because I couldn't speak English well.

Please understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand the question but I see an error which might cause all sorts of problems:

```html
<textarea id="id_content></textarea>
```

This is missing a double quote. Correct it to:

```html
<textarea id="id_content"></textarea>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.. i solved fix highlights code.

i vote your answer